# Determine facing direction from camera vector/yaw

Tags: java

I'm trying to determine the cardinal direction (west/north/east/south) that a player (camera) is facing. I have a 3d world setup with a camera that properly moves in any direction and I have the yaw/pitch and obviously the currently coordinates of the camera.

I've found several examples that determine another coordinate in the current direction but I only want the current direction - in radians most likely, then I can use that to determine a cardinal direction.

Comment: you use pitch/yaw only to compute the camera matrix ?

Comment: @Raxvan maybe roll is fixed at 0..., either way your yaw would be the value you are looking for

Comment: I've been playing with converting the yaw but nothing I'm trying works. I tried Math.toRadians but it always seems like a relative value, never between 0-360.

Comment: so to be clear you want to determine the pitch/yaw for your camera so that it will face a specific point p ?

Comment: Not quite - I want to extract a value that tells me which general direction the camera is facing. I don't need any new coordinates. For example, a value between 0-360 degrees to indicate facing direction, so I can then know if they're facing east, west, north, south. Eventually, it'd be nice to know if they're looking up/down too.

Comment: Whel for that you have the yaw and pitch already , why not use that ?

Comment: I'm sure how, that's why I'm looking for help. These old rusty math skills of mine.

Comment: Meh, I think I get it. My debug made it seem like yaw was always relative to my previous direction, but now that I look more closely it's not. It's between -3.14 and 3.14.